# Push Notification Second Tile

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-7.1, mpns

I can handle the second tile with a notification of wp7?
I can only do it on first.

Do you have any idea to offer me?

Surely management is possible using the raw notifications within the application and will handle me the tile, but are still forced to enter into the application to update.

Comment: Do you mean you cannot update the secondary tile using a push notification?

Comment: I'm just asking this question, is it possible? I'm slamming it in a while, but I can not find the solution to my problem.

Comment: It is possible. I've done it on a WP7 app. Are you sending the push and it is never being received? Double check the XML syntax you are sending and read the response to ensure there is a connection.

Comment: not clear to me your answer, you talk about the main or second tile?

Comment: for notifications in main tile there are no problems. for those in the second tile do not know how to move

Answer (score 1):

through aid, here's how I had to format the xml to send notification, I missed the tag ID

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <wp:Notification xmlns:wp=WPNotification>
  <wp:Tile ID="Navigation URI of the tile to update">
   <wp:BackgroundImage><string></wp:BackgroundImage>
   <wp:Count><string></wp:Count>
   <wp:Title><string></wp:Title>
   <wp:BackBackgroundImage><string></wp:BackBackgroundImage>
   <wp:BackTitle><string></wp:BackTitle>
   <wp:BackContent><string></wp:BackContent>
  </wp:Tile>
 </wp:Notification>
```

thx tomasmcguinness

Answer (score -1):

The MSDN documentation covers secondary tiles

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202945(v=vs.92).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202945%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

These paramters are the ones you use to update the secondary tile:

```
<wp:BackBackgroundImage>
<wp:BackTitle>
<wp:BackContent>
```

Populate these three elements in your push XML and that will update the back tile.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I do not speak of backTile, but an additional tile

Comment: sorry, here is a sample application that should help: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Get-to-Mango-7-Using-Push-39228be6